# How do I pick the right resistor for an optoisolator given a desired current?

Tags: datasheet, opto-isolator, ohms-law

This is a follow up to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73110/how-do-i-optimally-connect-elk-924-high-sensitivity-relay-board-to-dsc-pgm), but isn't specific to the other one.  This is both an ohm's law question and a 'how does one interpret data sheets' question.

I want to minimize the current I use to hold open a relay via a trigger (which only requires 1.2mA) that I need to isolate.  If I use, say, an NTE3083 optoisolator to trigger this relay, how do I pick the proper resistor for the optoisolator's input?   The datasheet says the NTE3083 will trigger as low as 1mA.

But the [datasheet](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/3000to3099/pdf/nte3083.pdf) doesn't give a definitive forward voltage.  It gives a 60mA forward current, and then has a table that also mentions 1.15V-1.5V and 20mA as part of its characteristics.

If my source voltage is 12V, and I want, say, 2mA to be conservative, how do I get there from here?

Do I just drop the voltage and current (R of the optoisolator would be constant?) by scaling down current and voltage?  So if I want 2mA, divide by 10:  20mA/10 and 1.15V (or 1.5??)/10?  And then calculate the resistor?

```
((12 volts) - (.1 volts)) / (2 milliamperes) = 5950 ohms
```

Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*the datasheet doesn't give a definitive forward voltage*

It does: The 1.15 Volts typical, 1.5 Volts maximum specified at 20 mA is the LED's forward voltage specification: It never is a precise voltage, LED voltages can vary greatly between units even within a single batch.

For calculating resistance for minimum current, in the absence of input V<sub>f</sub> versus current graphs in the datasheet, use the minimum forward voltage rating for calculations: Vf falls with decreasing current through the LED, but not linearly as the question indicates.

So, for 1 mA: `(12 - 1.15) / 0.001 = 10.85 kOhms`, use a standard value resistor of 10k.

Note that even if one uses the maximum V<sub>f</sub> from the datahsheet, the  results are 10.5k, not much difference.

**Note:**

With the CTR of the device specified as 200% minimum, 400% typical, a 1 mA input current would allow a nominal 2-4 mA of Collector Current to flow at the output if there were no other current limiting on the output circuit. This may not be sufficient to hold open the driven relay.

The **input current will need to be increased** to meet the required output current for the relay. Hence the above 1 mA "desired" current as specified in the question may well be invalid and irrelevant.

Comment: The relay board in question has a "sensitive trigger" that only requires 1.2mA to trigger.  I'll update that in the question.

Comment: @rrauenza Then you're all set, my answer covers what you need, I believe.